# How do I extract a variable from XML using Postman?

Tags: json, xml, postman

I'm trying to extract a SessionId from the XML which is returned from a SOAP API.

I've read through the Postman documentation (several times over) but it wasn't the most helpful in achieving my goal.

What was suggested in a few blogs was to convert the XML to JSON, and then pick out the token and it's value from there, but that didn't help either.

I used the following in my Test:

```
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("Session_Id", jsonObject.SessionID);
```

The above created the variable "Session_Id" but didn't actually assign a value to it. I'm stumped.

I'm definitely retrieving the data from the API, and it's viewable in Postman's "Body" Response.

Comment: I'm still seeking an answer to this, and I'm corroborating with the person who introduced me to the app. I'll send Postman an email if I don't come right in the next few days.

Comment: Whats the output for jsonObject and is jsonObject.SessionID a string. According to postman docs: postman.setGlobalVariable(variableName, variableValue): Sets a global variable "variableName", and assigns the string "variableValue" to it. Note: Only strings can be stored. Storing other types of data will result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: I emailed Postman @Shaughn and one of their founders replied, advising me of the same thing. But he went on to say that the app automatically converts any other type to a string.
Regardless, I found the issue. I wasn't drilling deep enough into the JSON blob. I ended up using:
'postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Session_Id", jsonObject.UserSessionToken.SessionId);'
I made use of the Console.log and kept checking the output until I found what I needed.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To extract a variable from XML using Postman, first convert your XML to JSON, using the xml2Json converter method:

```
var responseJson = xml2Json(responseBody);
```

(Where "responseBody" is your xml body.)
Then use the console.log method to output your JSON data, as such:

```
console.log(responseJson);
```

Be sure to have followed this tutorial on [Enabling Chrome Dev Tools in Postman](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/enabling-chrome-developer-tools-inside-postman/)

Inside your Test Runner, run the test, then right click and "Inspect" anywhere in the Runner. Select the "Console" tab once Chrome's Dev Tools launch. Expand the "Object" part.

Then drill-down (expand) until you see the Property whose data you need.
Thereafter, set the variable by appending each drill-down level to the parameter you want:

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("Session_Id", responseJson.UserSessionToken.SessionID);
```

In this case, "responseJson" is the object, "UserSessionToken" was the next level in the drill-down, and SessionId was the parameter I needed within that.

Comment: If you running the standalone app, you don't need to enable the tools via Chrome. Simply open from from the menu bar: View -> Show Postman Console

Comment: To complete the answer, if like me your xml tag are referencing xmlns with name such as s:body, just put those inside bracket like `responseJson['S:Envelope']['S:Body'].activation`

Comment: Note that the name of this function is wrong - it doesn't return a string of JSON, it returns _a JS object_, so the first sentence should read "first convert your XML into an object". Confusing the two concepts is a really bad idea.

Comment: I believe the last paragraph (the one beginning "Note:") is misleading.  I don't think the version number of postman has anything to do with the correctness of this answer.  Tom Redfern's answer, using square brackets instead of dots, is only needed if you have certain special characters in your field names.

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer did not work for me (it used to before the update to v7.15.0). If your field names have certain characters in them then put the path segments into square brackets.

For example, in the following XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<QuotesPrivateResponse>
    <lease-service>
        <duration-in-months>24</duration-in-months>
    </lease-service>
</QuotesPrivateResponse>
```

to retrieve the value *duration-in-months*:

```
var response = xml2Json(responseBody);
var duration = response["QuotesPrivateResponse"]["lease-service"]["duration-in-months"];
pm.environment.set("duration", duration);
```

This is necessary when any of the element names in your xml doc contain hyphens(-), underscores(_), or colons(:), and there may be other characters which cause this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Worked like a charm. Out of curiosity, where is this documented? Can't seem to find it on Postman's official docs.

Comment: @Ash sorry I must have found it somewhere, but I con't remember now.

Comment: The problem is not in version, json field names with dashes are the problem.   Example: duration-in-months

Comment: Thank you, I've been grappling with this for ever. It also works with dot in element names, which is supposedly illegal in JSONPath. Brilliant!

Answer (score 9):

Postman v7.20.1

I'd like to add my answer since above there are a couple of details that took me a while to solve:

- how to cope with a multipart SOAP response
- how to manage a JSON object
- responseBody definition

Here's the first lines of my XML response to analyze:

```
------=_Part_694527_1470506002.1584708814081
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=UTF-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: 
<e3bd82ac-d88f-49d4-8088-e07ff1c8d407>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <env:Header/>
        <env:Body>
            <ns2:GenericResponse xmlns:ns2="http://XXXXXXXX">
                <ns2:Service IdcService="XXXXXXXX">
                    <ns2:Document>
                        <ns2:Field name="XXXXXXXX:isSetDefault">1</ns2:Field>
                        <ns2:Field name="XXXXXXXX">CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL</ns2:Field>
```

After I noticed it was a multipart I've ended up with this Postman Test:

```
var response = pm.response.text();
var responseBody = response.substr(response.indexOf('<env:')); 

pm.test("The body of the response is a valid XML", function () {
     pm.expect(xml2Json(responseBody)).to.exist;
});


pm.test("UCM file upload checkin succesfull", function(){

    var responseJson = xml2Json(responseBody);
    var JsonFields = (responseJson['env:Envelope']['env:Body']['ns2:GenericResponse']['ns2:Service']['ns2:Document']['ns2:Field']);

    JsonFields.forEach( field => {
    if (field.name == 'StatusMessage'){
        console.log("Field = " + field.name);
        pm.expect(field.text().to.include("Successfully checked in"));
        }
    }); 
});
```