# How do I extract a variable within namespace from XML using Postman?

Tags: json, xml, postman, jsonpath, for-xml-path

I am trying to extract a session token using the same method described in this link [How do I extract a variable from XML using Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815414/how-do-i-extract-a-variable-from-xml-using-postman)

Have searched all over the web with no luck.

My xml has a namespace **se**:security

se is the namespace and security is the element. The token is within children.

So if i drill down i suppose it will be Security - binarycode - token (where the variable is)

But it doesn't work. Is it because of the namespace se?

I am doing the following in Postman Test window.

```
var responseJson = xml2Json(responseBody);
console.log(responseJson);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Token", responseJson.se.security.token);
```

Comment: Can you show your XML or something that has the same structure ?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Token", responseJson['se:security']);
```

Key things I found:

- Any key with a namespace does not take "."
- Keys with namespace must have square brackets and quotes
- Any key without a namespace uses only "."

For example:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Token", responseJson['se:security'].without['se:with']['se:with'].without.without
```