# API XML to JSON format and back to XML

Tags: javascript, json, xml, api

I'm using postman to test the following, later it will be automated but that's not the issue.

I'm requesting data from an XML based API and need to use the same data to send to a different API in XML format.

I've already figured out that I need to convert the XML to a JSON format in order to save it in a var. Which works.

However, the issue that I have is that this process creates extra characters in my data, in the form of: [{"$":

When I then continue to convert it back to XML (using the full function below), it doesn't work and I end up with an XML code with   all over it. Which isn't accepted in the last post to the XML Api.

I want to achieve to remove all occurences of  and  in the XML var. But I think that I will need to get rid of the in the first step. [{"$":

I've already found a function (.replace) which removes it, but only the first occurence

**Function JSON2XML**

```html
function json2xml(o, tab) {
   var toXml = function(v, name, ind) {
      var xml = "";
      if (v instanceof Array) {
         for (var i=0, n=v.length; i<n; i++)
            xml += ind + toXml(v[i], name, ind+"\t") + "\n";
      }
      else if (typeof(v) == "object") {
         var hasChild = false;
         xml += ind + "<" + name;
         for (var m in v) {
            if (m.charAt(0) == "@")
               xml += " " + m.substr(1) + "=\"" + v[m].toString() + "\"";
            else
               hasChild = true;
         }
         xml += hasChild ? ">" : "/>";
         if (hasChild) {
            for (var m in v) {
               if (m == "#text")
                  xml += v[m];
               else if (m == "#cdata")
                  xml += "<![CDATA[" + v[m] + "]]>";
               else if (m.charAt(0) != "@")
                  xml += toXml(v[m], m, ind+"\t");
            }
            xml += (xml.charAt(xml.length-1)=="\n"?ind:"") + "</" + name + ">";
         }
      }
      else {
         xml += ind + "<" + name + ">" + v.toString() +  "</" + name + ">";
      }
      return xml;
   }, xml="";
   for (var m in o)
      xml += toXml(o[m], m, "");
   return tab ? xml.replace(/\t/g, tab) : xml.replace(/\t|\n/g, "");
   

  
}



// Get the JSON from environment and parse it
let targetJSON = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('firstTarget'));

// Convert it to XML String
let xmlString = json2xml(targetJSON);

// You can check the console if your string is correct
console.log(xmlString);

// Store the XML string as a variable and use this variable in your request body
pm.environment.set('targetXML', xmlString);
```

```html
let resp = xml2Json(pm.response.text()),
    targetData = resp.eExact.Accounts;
console.log({ targetData });

pm.environment.set('firstTarget', JSON.stringify(targetData));
```

This is the code which creates the [{"$":

Comment: "I've already figured out that I need to convert the XML to a JSON format in order to save it in a var. " -> are you sure? The two formats _are not easily interchangeable_, so it's almost always better to keep the actual XML string around until you're ready to extract data from it, then extract _the actual data you need_, not try to automate the conversion in some way. Remember that XML and JSON are both just ways of storing data in strings; a JS object _is not_ JSON.

Comment: Well I first tried to just take the XML and put this in a variable but I can't seem to do this in Postman, I based myself on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815414/how-do-i-extract-a-variable-from-xml-using-postman

Though I don't actually need one specific value in this case, I really need the full XML and post this to a different API in the same format, with no changes (It's to sync data between multiple datasources which can't be done in the software itself.

Comment: I've added a second snippet with the code which creates the [{"$": and is ues to save the response in a var

Comment: The argument you're passing to `pm.environment.set('firstTarget', value)` is just a string; Postman doesn't care how you created that string. Since `pm.response.text()` is already a string, you should be able to write `pm.environment.set('firstTarget', pm.response.text());` Note also that the `xml2json` function is terribly named - it does nothing to do with JSON, it just parses the XML into a JS object.