# How can i pass an XML response to an environment variable in Postman?

Tags: javascript, xml, postman, postman-collection-runner

Here is the response i'm getting from my request :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session id="147xxxx"/>
```

I added this code to the tests tab of my request :

```
var XMLData = xml2Json(responseBody);
sessionId = pm.response.text("sessionId");
pm.environment.set("sessionId", sessionId);
```

It seems to work but all i'm getting is the entire response in my environment variable which is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session id="147xxxx"/>
```

But i only want the id in my environment variable.

Any ideas on how i could do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract a variable from XML using Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815414/how-do-i-extract-a-variable-from-xml-using-postman)

Comment: Saw this post already and tried the proposed solutions but none of them worked